# Pylint - Making a pylintrc config file minimalist

Tags: pylint

I am using Pylint to go through a bunch of **.py** files and do the following tests:

- bad-indentation
- mixed-indentation
- unused-variable

I also want to have my **pylintrc** file as minimalist as possible. This is what I had in the begging:

```
[MASTER]

# Use multiple processes to speed up Pylint.
jobs=1

# Pickle collected data for later comparisons.
persistent=yes

# Allow loading of arbitrary C extensions. Extensions are imported into the
# active Python interpreter and may run arbitrary code.
unsafe-load-any-extension=no


[MESSAGES CONTROL]

# Disable all to choose the Tests one by one
disable=all

# Tests
enable=bad-indentation,       # Used when an unexpected number of indentation’s tabulations or spaces has been found.
       mixed-indentation,     # Used when there are some mixed tabs and spaces in a module.
       unused-variable        # Used when a variable is defined but not used. (Use _var to ignore var).

[REPORTS]

# Set the output format. Available formats are text, parseable, colorized, json
# and msvs (visual studio).You can also give a reporter class, eg
# mypackage.mymodule.MyReporterClass.
output-format=text

# Tells whether to display a full report or only the messages
reports=no

# Activate the evaluation score.
score=no


[REFACTORING]

# Maximum number of nested blocks for function / method body
max-nested-blocks=5


[TYPECHECK]

# List of decorators that produce context managers, such as
# contextlib.contextmanager. Add to this list to register other decorators that
# produce valid context managers.
contextmanager-decorators=contextlib.contextmanager

# Tells whether missing members accessed in mixin class should be ignored. A
# mixin class is detected if its name ends with "mixin" (case insensitive).
ignore-mixin-members=yes

# This flag controls whether pylint should warn about no-member and similar
# checks whenever an opaque object is returned when inferring. The inference
# can return multiple potential results while evaluating a Python object, but
# some branches might not be evaluated, which results in partial inference. In
# that case, it might be useful to still emit no-member and other checks for
# the rest of the inferred objects.
ignore-on-opaque-inference=yes

# List of class names for which member attributes should not be checked (useful
# for classes with dynamically set attributes). This supports the use of
# qualified names.
ignored-classes=optparse.Values,thread._local,_thread._local

# Show a hint with possible names when a member name was not found. The aspect
# of finding the hint is based on edit distance.
missing-member-hint=yes

# The minimum edit distance a name should have in order to be considered a
# similar match for a missing member name.
missing-member-hint-distance=1

# The total number of similar names that should be taken in consideration when
# showing a hint for a missing member.
missing-member-max-choices=1


[MISCELLANEOUS]

# List of note tags to take in consideration, separated by a comma.
notes=FIXME,XXX,TODO


[SIMILARITIES]

# Ignore comments when computing similarities.
ignore-comments=yes

# Ignore docstrings when computing similarities.
ignore-docstrings=yes

# Ignore imports when computing similarities.
ignore-imports=no

# Minimum lines number of a similarity.
min-similarity-lines=4


[LOGGING]

# Logging modules to check that the string format arguments are in logging
# function parameter format
logging-modules=logging


[BASIC]

# Naming hint for argument names
argument-name-hint=(([a-z][a-z0-9_]{2,30})|(_[a-z0-9_]*))$

# Regular expression matching correct argument names
argument-rgx=(([a-z][a-z0-9_]{2,30})|(_[a-z0-9_]*))$

# Naming hint for attribute names
attr-name-hint=(([a-z][a-z0-9_]{2,30})|(_[a-z0-9_]*))$

# Regular expression matching correct attribute names
attr-rgx=(([a-z][a-z0-9_]{2,30})|(_[a-z0-9_]*))$

# Bad variable names which should always be refused, separated by a comma
bad-names=foo,bar,baz,toto,tutu,tata

# Naming hint for class attribute names
class-attribute-name-hint=([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]{2,30}|(__.*__))$

# Regular expression matching correct class attribute names
class-attribute-rgx=([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]{2,30}|(__.*__))$

# Naming hint for class names
class-name-hint=[A-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]+$

# Regular expression matching correct class names
class-rgx=[A-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]+$

# Naming hint for constant names
const-name-hint=(([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$

# Regular expression matching correct constant names
const-rgx=(([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$

# Minimum line length for functions/classes that require docstrings, shorter
# ones are exempt.
docstring-min-length=-1

# Naming hint for function names
function-name-hint=(([a-z][a-z0-9_]{2,30})|(_[a-z0-9_]*))$

# Regular expression matching correct function names
function-rgx=(([a-z][a-z0-9_]{2,30})|(_[a-z0-9_]*))$

# Good variable names which should always be accepted, separated by a comma
good-names=i,j,k,ex,Run,_

# Include a hint for the correct naming format with invalid-name
include-naming-hint=no

# Naming hint for inline iteration names
inlinevar-name-hint=[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*$

# Regular expression matching correct inline iteration names
inlinevar-rgx=[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*$

# Naming hint for method names
method-name-hint=(([a-z][a-z0-9_]{2,30})|(_[a-z0-9_]*))$

# Regular expression matching correct method names
method-rgx=(([a-z][a-z0-9_]{2,30})|(_[a-z0-9_]*))$

# Naming hint for module names
module-name-hint=(([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+))$

# Regular expression matching correct module names
module-rgx=(([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+))$

# Regular expression which should only match function or class names that do
# not require a docstring.
no-docstring-rgx=^_

# List of decorators that produce properties, such as abc.abstractproperty. Add
# to this list to register other decorators that produce valid properties.
property-classes=abc.abstractproperty

# Naming hint for variable names
variable-name-hint=(([a-z][a-z0-9_]{2,30})|(_[a-z0-9_]*))$

# Regular expression matching correct variable names
variable-rgx=(([a-z][a-z0-9_]{2,30})|(_[a-z0-9_]*))$


[VARIABLES]

# List of additional names supposed to be defined in builtins. Remember that
# you should avoid to define new builtins when possible.
#additional-builtins=

# Tells whether unused global variables should be treated as a violation.
allow-global-unused-variables=yes

# List of strings which can identify a callback function by name. A callback
# name must start or end with one of those strings.
callbacks=cb_,_cb

# A regular expression matching the name of dummy variables (i.e. expectedly
# not used).
dummy-variables-rgx=_+$|(_[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+?$)|dummy|^ignored_|^unused_

# Argument names that match this expression will be ignored. Default to name
# with leading underscore
ignored-argument-names=_.*|^ignored_|^unused_

# Tells whether we should check for unused import in __init__ files.
init-import=no

# List of qualified module names which can have objects that can redefine
# builtins.
redefining-builtins-modules=six.moves,future.builtins


[SPELLING]

# Tells whether to store unknown words to indicated private dictionary in
# --spelling-private-dict-file option instead of raising a message.
spelling-store-unknown-words=no


[FORMAT]

# Regexp for a line that is allowed to be longer than the limit.
ignore-long-lines=^\s*(# )?<?https?://\S+>?$

# Number of spaces of indent required inside a hanging or continued line.
indent-after-paren=4

# String used as indentation unit. This is usually "    " (4 spaces) or "\t" (1
# tab).
indent-string='    '

# Maximum number of characters on a single line.
max-line-length=125

# Maximum number of lines in a module
max-module-lines=1000

# List of optional constructs for which whitespace checking is disabled. `dict-
# separator` is used to allow tabulation in dicts, etc.: {1  : 1,\n222: 2}.
# `trailing-comma` allows a space between comma and closing bracket: (a, ).
# `empty-line` allows space-only lines.
no-space-check=trailing-comma,dict-separator

# Allow the body of a class to be on the same line as the declaration if body
# contains single statement.
single-line-class-stmt=no

# Allow the body of an if to be on the same line as the test if there is no
# else.
single-line-if-stmt=no


[CLASSES]

# List of method names used to declare (i.e. assign) instance attributes.
defining-attr-methods=__init__,__new__,setUp

# List of member names, which should be excluded from the protected access
# warning.
exclude-protected=_asdict,_fields,_replace,_source,_make

# List of valid names for the first argument in a class method.
valid-classmethod-first-arg=cls

# List of valid names for the first argument in a metaclass class method.
valid-metaclass-classmethod-first-arg=mcs


[IMPORTS]

# Allow wildcard imports from modules that define __all__.
allow-wildcard-with-all=no

# Analyse import fallback blocks. This can be used to support both Python 2 and
# 3 compatible code, which means that the block might have code that exists
# only in one or another interpreter, leading to false positives when analysed.
analyse-fallback-blocks=no

# Deprecated modules which should not be used, separated by a comma
deprecated-modules=regsub,TERMIOS,Bastion,rexec

# Force import order to recognize a module as part of a third party library.
known-third-party=enchant


[DESIGN]

# Maximum number of arguments for function / method
max-args=5

# Maximum number of attributes for a class (see R0902).
max-attributes=7

# Maximum number of boolean expressions in a if statement
max-bool-expr=5

# Maximum number of branch for function / method body
max-branches=12

# Maximum number of locals for function / method body
max-locals=15

# Maximum number of parents for a class (see R0901).
max-parents=7

# Maximum number of public methods for a class (see R0904).
max-public-methods=20

# Maximum number of return / yield for function / method body
max-returns=6

# Maximum number of statements in function / method body
max-statements=50

# Minimum number of public methods for a class (see R0903).
min-public-methods=2


[EXCEPTIONS]

# Exceptions that will emit a warning when being caught.
overgeneral-exceptions=Exception
```

Can I just simplify it to this:

```
[MASTER]

# Use multiple processes to speed up Pylint.
jobs=1


[MESSAGES CONTROL]

# Disable all to choose the Tests one by one
disable=all

# Tests
enable=bad-indentation,       # Used when an unexpected number of indentation’s tabulations or spaces has been found.
       mixed-indentation,     # Used when there are some mixed tabs and spaces in a module.
       unnecessary-semicolon, # Used when a statement is ended by a semi-colon (”;”), which isn’t necessary.
       unused-variable        # Used when a variable is defined but not used. (Use _var to ignore var).


[REPORTS]

# Tells whether to display a full report or only the messages
reports=no

# Activate the evaluation score.
score=no


[FORMAT]

# Regexp for a line that is allowed to be longer than the limit.
ignore-long-lines=^\s*(# )?<?https?://\S+>?$

# Number of spaces of indent required inside a hanging or continued line.
indent-after-paren=4

# String used as indentation unit. This is usually "    " (4 spaces) or "\t" (1
# tab).
indent-string='    '

# Maximum number of lines in a module
max-module-lines=1000


[EXCEPTIONS]

# Exceptions that will emit a warning when being caught.
overgeneral-exceptions=Exception
```

I believe that if I'm only doing those tests many of the other lines were completely useless. What happens if I remove one of the lines? Does it get its default values?

For example if I set `reports=no` I don't need to have the line `output-format=text`, right? And if I remove `jobs=1` line will it still be the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you don't define any value in the pylint configuration, it is going to use its default known value.